# How to fully uninstall the Cocoapods from the Mac Machine?

Tags: ios, macos

I installed Cocoapods version 0.28, and now I want to uninstall it from my machine. How can I do that?

Answer (score 150):

First, determine which version(s) of Cocoapods you have installed by running this in Terminal:

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
```

You see output similar to this:

```
cocoapods (0.27.1, 0.20.2)
cocoapods-core (0.27.1, 0.20.2)
cocoapods-downloader (0.2.0, 0.1.2)
```

Here, I have two versions of Cocoapods installed.

To completely remove, issue the following commands:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods
gem uninstall cocoapods-core
gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

If you have multiple versions installed, like I have, it will prompt you to choice a specific version or all. If you want to uninstall a specific version you can also use the `-v` switch as follows:

```
gem uninstall cocoapods -v 0.20.2
```

Running `gem list --local | grep cocoapods` again will confirm that Cocoapods has been removed.

You may have residual artefacts in a hidden folder in your home directory. Remove these with:

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
```

Comment: add sudo before every command if it gives error like "You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory". For e-g sudo gem uninstall cocoapods

Comment: You may also want to remove the files cocoapods creates with: `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods`

Comment: Thanks sir. However mine were in a Ruby folder so Terminal hinted: try this command instead: 'gem uninstall -i /Users/Rob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global cocoapods'

Comment: gem list doesn't list cocoa pods as installed on my Mac, yet there is a large hidden cocoapods directory in my home directory. How to continue from there? where should I look for cocoapods leftovers? I cannot rely on gem here.

Comment: @MottiShneor From two comments above your's: `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods`.

Comment: on Monterey seems we need sudo. II Norte: we can write multiple cmd on the same line:
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods  cocoapods-core  cocoapods-downloader

Answer (score 46):

I used the following bash script to remove all the relevant gems.

```
for i in $( gem list --local --no-version | grep cocoapods );
do 
    gem uninstall $i; 
done
```

Additionally delete `~/.cocoapods` to remove the cache of podspecs.

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/
```

Comment: This is the complete answer

Comment: this is same and better: `gem list --local --no-version | grep cocoapods | xargs gem uninstall`

Comment: I need sudo for do `gem uninstall`, so I modified the bash like this (one line command):

`for i in $( gem list --local --no-version | grep cocoapods ); do  sudo gem uninstall $i; done`

Answer (score 35):

```
gem list --local --no-versions | grep cocoapods | xargs sudo gem uninstall
sudo rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, thanks! Together with `sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master` it finally removed everything.

Answer (score 12):

Easy, just run the following command to remove all or just a specific cocoapod gem:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have 2 versions of cocoapods installed and you cannot figure out why or how to delete them, I would ask you this ...

At some point in the past, did you run this command?

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

If your answer is yes and you are struggling to find an answer .. do like me and run:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Get it? :) That should fix the "other" version of cocoapods .. now you are only left with the gem one.

Now you should be ok to just run a `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` and then again `sudo gem install cocoapods` for a clean install.

I would also check this answer as it cleans the caches as well :) https://superuser.com/a/686319/1276003.

Answer (score 1):

I was following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/686319/673121) but for Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11 I was encountering an error as below on executing `gem uninstall -n cocoapods` command

```
pranav-MacBook-Pro:~ pranavpranav$ gem uninstall -n cocoapods
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)
```

In order to overcome the issue with permissions you must use the below command

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -n /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what perfectly work for me.

1. Uninstall CocoaPods (choose to uninstall all versions):

   sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
2. Remove old master repo:

   sudo rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master

Comment: This would be less confusing if you included only the information necessary to uninstall. Adding the bits about reinstallation doesn't make sense as part of an answer to this question.

Comment: thanx, i will do it next time.

Answer (score 0):

Remove lib form Podfile, then pod install again.